# Criar script para executar programa passando apenas parte do nome

Tags: windows, cmd, linha-de-comando

Criei um pequeno script (`.bat`) para a instalação de vários programas de forma silenciosa.

Com o tempo os programas vão atualizando exigindo que eu edite o código para colocar o número da versão do programa.

**Dúvida:** Seria possível dizer ao CMD que independente do final do nome do programa ele consiga localizar esse programa e instalar?

Exemplo de como está.

```
start cmd /C "Winrar 5.40 (x64)" /S
start cmd /C "Chrome 56" /silent /install
start cmd /C "Firefox 52.0 (x64)" -ms
```

Exemplo de como queria que estivesse. (Localize independente do final do nome principal).

```
start cmd /C "Winrar *" /S
start cmd /C "Chrome *" /silent /install
start cmd /C "Firefox *" -ms
```

Estudei SQL e quando precisa dizer tudo usamos `*`.

Pensei que poderia usar `*` para fazer o mesmo no CMD mais isso não se aplica 
porque cada linguagem é uma situação.

Comment: Você está fazendo um script para isso ou irá fazer manual?

Comment: Eu entendi errado ou ele precisa de ajuda para criar um batch script? Não entendi porque está fora do escopo.

Comment: Junior, tente [edit] sua questão e explicar melhor o que precisa fazer e onde está a dificuldade. Deu pra entender um pouco a parte de ignorar o numero, mas ainda faltam detalhes para se imaginar de onde vai vir o nome, qual o critério pra saber o que executar, e vários outros pontos. Caso a edição torne a duvida clara, e esteja realmente no escopo do site, ela pode ser reaberta.

Comment: Atualizei o texto espero que ajude a esclarecer.

Comment: @Bacco considerou reabrir agora?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart precisa de mais 4 votos para reabrir além do meu. Ainda tem algumas coisas que poderiam ser melhor explicadas, por exemplo, se tiver 2 executáveis com o mesmo começo no mesmo diretório, qual o critério, etc.

Comment: @Bacco Entendi. Só fiquei em dúvida se o pessoal que votou para fechar viu a edição.

Comment: @MurilloGoulart não precisa ser o mesmo pessoal. Qualquer pessoa com pontuação suficiente vê a edição na fila de análise. Quaisquer 5 votos abrem.

Comment: Ola Murillo tudo bem eu estava procurando exatamente esse bat eu só precisaria se vc pudesse me ajudar em relação ao mesmo, como eu faço para que ele tamben execute um arquivo (msi) criar um bat só e que quando colocar ele em uma pasta com programa .exe ele ira executar como tamben se esse mesmo bat eu colocar em uma pasta com um programa .msi ele tamben execute e no mode de administrador
Desde de ja muito obrigo e aguardo retorno
At: James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salve o conteúdo abaixo como `exec.bat`:

```
@echo off
    setlocal
    set EXECUTAVEL=
    for %%i in (%1*.exe) do set EXECUTAVEL=%%i
    if /i not "%EXECUTAVEL%"=="" (
       echo Executando "%EXECUTAVEL%"...
       call "%EXECUTAVEL%"
    )
    endlocal
```

Execute na pasta corrente do executável:

```
exec Chrome
```

Comment: Na linha 4 eu editei e coloquei (Firefox%1*.exe). Quando vai executar a linha -> call %EXECUTAVEL% o CMD finaliza mesmo exibindo o nome completo do programa após ativar echo para on.

Comment: O script está pronto, você não deve editar. Por que não executa? exec exec Firefox?

Comment: CMD não entende o que é exec Firefox...

Comment: O batch deve estar nesta pasta. É o mesmo que executar exec.bat Firefox, entende?

Comment: CMD está exibindo -> set EXECUTAVEL=Firefox 52.0 (x64).exe e depois fecha.

OBS: Deixei as configurações que você enviou.

Comment: Parênteses é caractere especial. Ajustei o batch para considerar isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56248/discussion-between-murillo-goulart-and-junior).